# AoE initiator for Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx

Does anyone know an implementation of an AoE initiator for Mac OS X?

Comment: Nobody compiles aoetools for MacOS X ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GraniteSTOR](http://www.granitestor.com/) EasyAoE

Comment: +1, Thanks for this link, I was looking for the same.